# Determine judging parameters for a code in Linux

Tags: linux, compilation

I am developing an online code judging software for c/c++/java codes.

I want to include various parameters for judging a code ,namely compilation time,execution time,memory usage ,just like the IDEONE API  provides with.

How can i  extract these parameters while compiling/executing a code in a LINUX environment?Are there any specific commands?

Also are there any other parameters which can be used to judge a code?

Comment: IF you are not willing to help please atleast do not vote down, if you do tell me the reason!

Comment: You probably mean some *source code* (saying just *code* is a bit ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *judge* verb is a bit strange in your question (which is perhaps too imprecise). Maybe you mean *evaluate* ?

Assuming the evaluated source code is compiled by a recent GCC compiler (i.e. version 4.7 or 4.8 of GCC) and that you can parameterize (or just repeat) its compilation, you could consider ***extending & customizing*** the **GCC** compiler for evaluation or metric purposes. This is possible either directly thru GCC plugins (painfully coded in C or C++), or thru [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions (MELT is a domain specific language to extend and customize GCC).

You'll need some work to go this route, because you need to dive into GCC internals. The [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) might help you in understanding more the Gimple representation (inside GCC). You could also try compiling some sample code with `gcc -fdump-tree-all` which produce many dump files.

So the idea is that you would take time (days, perhaps weeks) to develop a MELT extension (e.g. in some file `shiven.melt`) for analysis, metrics and evaluation purposes, and that you would [re-] compile the `example.c` source code, e.g. with

```
gcc -fplugin=melt \
  -fplugin-arg-melt-extra=shiven \
  -fplugin-arg-melt-mode=shivenanalysis \
  -c example.c
```

(of course you'll add other compiler flags, e.g. `-O -I/some/include/dir/` ...)

Then, you could make a MELT extension to measure some characteristics of the compiled code, like number of functions, number of basic blocks, number of Gimple instructions, etc. This will happen at compilation time. Your MELT extension (in your file `shiven.melt`) could e.g. write some statistics in some database.

Extending GCC is meaningful for C, C++, Fortran, Ada .... source code, but much less for Java (because nobody uses GCC to compile Java, even if `gcj` exists, and because `gcj` probably supports a subset of some old Java standard).

Please subscribe to [gcc-melt@googlegroups](http://groups.google.com/group/gcc-melt) list and ask there for MELT related questions. Mention explicitly your MELT interest (perhaps your question) in your subscription.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `time` command which gives you the execution time of a binary. With that you can get the compilation time, `time gcc code.c`, or execution time, `time ./a.out`. For memory usage you can use `valgrind`, or `ps`. With ps, if you are using stdin for input it should be simple. Just start the application, run ps at certain intervals in the backgound, and supply the input to the application.